# F sharp method signature

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

What should the first line of a function that returns this value be?

> val memberof : ’a * ’a list -> bool when ’a : equality

I tried the following block to no avail. The code itself works but I get an extra tag when I put in in the interpreter.

```
let rec memberof (a, list)=
    match list with
        | [] ->false
        | x::xs -> if x=a then true else memberof(a, xs)
```

What I get is

> val memberof : a:'a * list:'a list -> bool when 'a : equality

How can I get rid of the a: before 'a ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `a` and the `list` before the `:` in the type signature are just the names of the two parameters that your function is taking. You can see that if you rename them, the signature changes too:

```
> let rec memberof (element, inputList)=
    match inputList with
    | [] ->false
    | x::xs -> if x=element then true else memberof(element, xs)
  ;;    
val memberof : element:'a * inputList:'a list -> bool when 'a : equality
```

I do not see why you would want to get rid of them - they're just an additional useful part of the type signature. That said, if you change the code so that the compiler cannot directly map the name(s) you use to the parameters, it will omit it. For example:

```
> let rec memberof arg = 
    let (element, inputList) = arg
    match inputList with
    | [] ->false
    | x::xs -> if x=element then true else memberof(element, xs)
;;
val memberof : 'a * 'a list -> bool when 'a : equality
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about this since the expected output format from this function was given to me beforehand. I know a and list are the names of parameters but the compiler not being able to map them seems like a good explanation.